# How to enable desktop effects in VMware?

Tags: nvidia, virtualization, vmware, desktop-environments

I am using VMware Workstation 7. I have the VMware tools and 3D acceleration enabled but when I try to enable desktop effects I get the message "Desktop effects could not be enabled". I have an Nvidia GeForce graphic card. And mine is a Dell XPS L501X .

Comment: why are you using vmware?i would recommend virtualbox instead of vmware.

Answer (score 1):

Both VMWare and VirtualBox limit the amount of video-RAM available to the guest OS.  As a result, the guest OS will assume that the machine isn't powerful enough to run desktop effects.  Keep in mind that the graphics card that the guest OS sees is what the emulator tells it.

Answer (score 0):

I think desktop effects will not run if it is not a recognized card. In my experienced, trying to run effects in a virtual machine has constantly failed. The reason may be because the video card inside the VM is not based on actual hardware.

Run this in the VM to check:

```
$ lspci | grep -i VGA | awk '{print "sudo lspci -knn -s "$1}' | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Desktop effects can be used on the VM install, but the 3d acceleration is software based, not hardware. This basically means that using the 3d effects will significantly slow down your VM.